# Apple simple ping not work on iOS why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I am using apple simple ping source code it works for MAC but not works on iOS.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html
below is code I am writing

```
ping = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
ping.delegate = self;
[ping start];
```

console response

```
2016-03-18 18:11:07.252 PinPin[383:49747] >CFHostStartInfoResolution
2016-03-18 18:11:07.256 PinPin[383:49747] <CFHostStartInfoResolution
2016-03-18 18:11:07.334 PinPin[383:49747] >HostResolveCallback
2016-03-18 18:11:07.336 PinPin[383:49747] didStartWithAddress
16-03-18 18:22:42.375 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:44.382 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:46.388 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:48.419 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:50.422 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:52.820 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:54.852 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:56.857 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:22:58.862 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:23:00.844 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:23:02.855 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:23:05.178 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
2016-03-18 18:23:07.006 PinPin[383:49747] didReceiveUnexpectedPacket
```

Nothing happens after this, no other delegate called like

```
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet;
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error;
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet;
```

And in readMe.txt apple say

"SimplePing runs on Mac OS X 10.7 and later, although the **core code works just fine on all versions of iOS** and the underlying approach works on earlier versions of Mac OS X (back to 10.2)."

// UPDATE

MAC. response

```
Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$  cd ~/Downloads/SimplePing
Anands-MacBook-Air:SimplePing anand$ build/Debug/SimplePing www.apple.com
2016-03-19 19:55:48.042 SimplePing[1149:19595] >CFHostStartInfoResolution
2016-03-19 19:55:48.045 SimplePing[1149:19595] <CFHostStartInfoResolution
2016-03-19 19:55:49.490 SimplePing[1149:19595] >HostResolveCallback
2016-03-19 19:55:49.491 SimplePing[1149:19595] pinging 23.211.220.146
2016-03-19 19:55:49.491 SimplePing[1149:19595] #0 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:49.551 SimplePing[1149:19595] #0 received
2016-03-19 19:55:50.493 SimplePing[1149:19595] #1 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:50.557 SimplePing[1149:19595] #1 received
2016-03-19 19:55:51.495 SimplePing[1149:19595] #2 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:51.553 SimplePing[1149:19595] #2 received
2016-03-19 19:55:52.493 SimplePing[1149:19595] #3 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:52.551 SimplePing[1149:19595] #3 received
2016-03-19 19:55:53.493 SimplePing[1149:19595] #4 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:53.551 SimplePing[1149:19595] #4 received
2016-03-19 19:55:54.497 SimplePing[1149:19595] #5 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:54.556 SimplePing[1149:19595] #5 received
2016-03-19 19:55:55.494 SimplePing[1149:19595] #6 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:55.550 SimplePing[1149:19595] #6 received
2016-03-19 19:55:56.492 SimplePing[1149:19595] #7 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:56.551 SimplePing[1149:19595] #7 received
2016-03-19 19:55:57.498 SimplePing[1149:19595] #8 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:57.562 SimplePing[1149:19595] #8 received
2016-03-19 19:55:58.494 SimplePing[1149:19595] #9 sent
2016-03-19 19:55:58.552 SimplePing[1149:19595] #9 received
```

Comment: where is your ping declared? almost sure you are releasing it

Comment: Init via ->     ping = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];, and why I need to release ?

Comment: I think he's saying it is being auto-released. Did you try retaining it with a strong reference?

Comment: You don't. but maybe you are auto-releasing it; Next question what do you do in `- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address` - ? - can you update your question with `didStartWithAddress` delegate?

Comment: Also, did you check if the SimplePing is still sending data?

Comment: @sken3r.MI  Right now nothing else log in "- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address - "

Comment: In my case when i give a non existing ip in my local router connected devices it just sending the packet and not showing failed or received data. how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `didStartWithAddress`:

```
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address 
{
    [pinger sendPingWithData:nil];
}
```

Comment: It works, but the thing is how you know this "[pinger sendPingWithData:nil];" , still response is not like MAC version runs.

Comment: But what happens in MAC app. please check update in question.

Comment: sorry i am not really familiar with this `SimplePing` i used it a long time a go, i don't even remember for what :D